# moveTo not working with onClick event in dojox.mobile.ListItem

Tags: dojo, dojox.mobile

I am developing a web page using Dojo mobile v1.5.1.

Below is the sample code.

```
<div dojotype="dojox.mobile.View" selected="true" id="view1">
  <div dojotype="dojox.mobile.Heading" label="dojox.mobile.Heading"></div>
  <div dojotype="dojox.mobile.EdgeToEdgeCategory" label=
  "dojox.mobile.EdgeToEdgeCategory"></div>
<div dojotype="dojox.mobile.EdgeToEdgeList">

  <!-- PROBLEM IS IN THIS DIV TAG -->
  <div dojotype="dojox.mobile.ListItem" moveto="view2" transition="slide"
  label="dojox.mobile.ListItem" onclick=
  "document.getElementById(&quot;cfText&quot;).innerText = &quot;Value set&quot;;"
  id="listItem1"></div>

</div>
</div>

<div dojotype="dojox.mobile.View" id="view2">
<div dojotype="dojox.mobile.Heading" label="dojox.mobile.Heading" back="Back" moveto=
"view1"></div>
<div dojotype="dojox.mobile.EdgeToEdgeList">
  <div dojotype="dojox.mobile.ListItem">
    <span id="cfText" class="xspTextComputedField">Value NOT set</span>
  </div>
</div>
</div>
```

**What it does is, when the div tag with with id "listItem1" is clicked it shows div tag with id "view2". But when I add the onClick event in it, it does NOT work. Without the onClick event it works fine.**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

GOT IT!

Add the following script:

```
<script type="text/javascript"> 
function setValue() {
    var cfText = dojo.byId("cfText");
    cfText.innerHTML = "Value Set";
}
dojo.addOnLoad(
    function() {
        dojo.connect(dijit.byId("listItem1"), "onClick", dojo.hitch(dijit.byId("listItem1"), setValue));
    }
);
</script>
```

Also remove the "onClick" attribute value from div tag with id "listItem1".

Thanks to [**this discussion**](http://dojo-toolkit.33424.n3.nabble.com/dojox-mobile-ListItem-onClick-event-td3160130.html) for helping me out.

Answer (score -1):

What are you trying to do with the onclick event?

Couldn't you rewrite that line like the following:

```
<div dojotype="dojox.mobile.ListItem" transition="slide"
  label="dojox.mobile.ListItem" onclick="someNewFunction(this)" id="listItem1">
```

Then create a new function to do what you want:

```
function someNewFunction(obj) {
  var cfText = dojo.byId("cfText");
  cfText.innerHTML = "Value";
  obj.transitionTo("move2");
}
```

Hope that helps and I understood you correctly.

EDIT:

Also I when I tried to use moveTo with an onClick on a listItem the onClick would work and the moveTo would not.  You can remove the moveTo attribute and add this line in the last line of your new function:

```
this.transitionTo("move2");
```

EDIT AGAIN:

Also you could remove the transition as well and add it to the transitionTo call.

Comment: Thanks for replying. But your solution does not work. Instead it throws an error: Object [object DOMWindow] has no method 'transitionTo'. I guess it is trying to all transitionTo in current window's object. I tried calling it on div object but it also throws error.

I am trying to set a value in "view2" and then display it using the moveTo attribute. I found [this link](http://dojo-toolkit.33424.n3.nabble.com/dojox-mobile-ListItem-onClick-event-td3160130.html) where the user is having a similar problem as me. But I am unable to incorporate the solution in my problem.

Comment: Sorry.  This needs to refer to the listItem object.  I'll edit my post again

Comment: Also in statement "this.transitionTo("move2");", I think you meant "view2" instead of "move2"